# Select contracts that are only in the notification period or are expired

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a SQL Server 2005 table called 'Contracts':

```
CREATE TABLE Contracts (
    ContractNo int not null,
    ExpirationDate smalldatetime not null,
    NotificationInAdvancedDays int not null
)
```

I want to display only the contracts that are within the notification period (`ExpirationDate+DaysNotificationInAdvanced`) or contracts that are expired (`ExpirationDate<CurrentDate`).

Comment: I've marked up your code so the final comparison is visible, and converted your narrative of the table into a CREATE TABLE statement (these tend to be easier to read, and people can then run them on their own servers, try out answers, etc). Your first condition isn't clear (there's no comparison specified), and I wouldn't guarantee that the table defn is 100% correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Contracts 
WHERE GETDATE() > DATEADD(day,-1*daysInAdvance,expirationDate) 
OR expirationDate < GETDATE()
```

Comment: I'm sorry, next time, I will.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function in SQL Server.

With it, you can do this in your where clause:

```
where (GetDate() > DateAdd(DAY, DaysNotificationAdvanced * -1, ExpirationDate) OR GetDate() > ExpirationDate)
```

Since there is no DateSubtract function in SQL Server, I mulitplied DaysNotificationAdvanced by -1 to subtract it from ExpirationDate.

Update: As JNK mentions in the comments, you don't really need to have the second condition in the where clause " OR GetDate() > ExpirationDate" if you are looking to return the contracts that are in the notification period or later.

Perhaps you could enhance the select list in the query to indicate whether the contract is in the notification period or expired:

```
SELECT ContractNo, 
       ExpirationDate,
       DaysNotificationAdvanced
       CASE WHEN GETDATE() > ExpirationDate THEN 'Expired' 
       ELSE 'About To Expire' END AS ContractStatus
FROM Contracts
WHERE GetDate() > DateAdd(DAY, DaysNotificationAdvanced * -1, ExpirationDate
```

Comment: Logically we don't even need his second requirement - if the current date is after the start of the notification period, it will either be in the period OR it will be expired.

Comment: @JNK, you're correct, I have updated the answer to include your comment